# Core Data: How to design a tree data structure from one core data entry

Tags: iphone, ios, database, xcode, core-data

I am struggling with designing a `coreData` model where I have only one type of entry called "To-Do". Each To-Do entry has either 0, 1, 2, ... , or n relationships to other (sub) entries just like To-Do. So the relationships between the To-Do entries design a tree structure with an undefined number of child nodes. The following graphic should illustrate the case (E = core data entry):

```
            E                            
           /|\                        
          / | \                       
         E  E  E                     
        / \               
       /   \         
      E     E               
     /|\                   
    E E E
```

My guess was to model that data like illustrated in the following graph. I didn't choose the inverse relationship because Xcode made a many-to-many relationship out of it which doesn't match the tree design.

[image]

Also I saw in the `data model inspector` something called "parent entry". So I started to believe I might have to create a second entry named "To-Do-Child" with the same attributes and make the other entry to the parent entry. The manual tells me that this might be the wrong path to go...

Questions:

1. **How can I model this approach within the core data model file?** Is one of the ones mentioned correct?
2. **How will I be able to fetch all To-Do entries of a specified parent node?** Since they arise from the same entry I have problems to address the exact To-Do subtree I want.

Comment: Just linking to this question which is a bit more useful than the accepted answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16633907/model-a-tree-structure-in-core-data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need a relationship of `parent` (destination entity is your to do entity) which serves as the destination for the inverse relationship.

Entries at the top of the tree have nil value for this relationship.

For any to-do item, the set returned from the childToDos relationship will hold all the children. It doesn't matter that these are of the same class.

Comment: Aha, nice idea. But then it came to my mind why not define a second relationship named `parent`. Wouldn't that do the trick as well without having a new attribute? So the first approach with the self relationship would be the right approach?

Comment: Correct, that is what I meant, sorry. I have updated the answer.