# Model a tree structure in Core Data

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data

I want to implement a multi-way tree using core data. There's a "Plan" entity in my core data model.

```
            Plan
           /  |  \
        Plan Plan Plan
     /  | \   |     |   \
   Plan Plan ...
```

The plan of the higher level will have to-many relationship with the sub-plans.

So how should I set the relationship?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would define

- a *to-many* relationship `subplans` (or `children`) from the *Plan* entity to itself, with the "Delete Rule" set to "Cascade",
- a *to-one* relationship `superplan` (or `parent`) from the *Plan* entity to itself, with the "Delete Rule" set to "Nullify",
- and set these as inverse relationships of each other.

If you delete one *Plan* object, then automatically

- all sub-plans are deleted due to the "Cascade" delete rule, and
- the plan is removed from its parent object due to the "Nullify" delete rule.

Comment: how would you store and retrieve data in sub-plan please give an example