# CoreData: Entity that has sub-entities with the same type

Tags: ios, swift, database, core-data

I have two entities in my `CoreData` model Form and Element which are related to each other as follows:

[image]

However, there is a requirement to have sub-forms for each form, or in other words, the received `JSON` has the main form and sub-forms for each form, each of which has the same main form attributes & relation (formID, formTitle, reporterName & elements).

what is the best design for this requirement ?

Comment: Do you mean something like this: [Model a tree structure in Core Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16633907/model-a-tree-structure-in-core-data) ?

Comment: @MartinR I've read your answer, it's a good idea, but I have 2 questions: 1) at the time when I fill the form entity with data should I just create a blank Form entity and set its Parent & Children relationships ? 2) is the setup you described enough for the "elements" relationship ? i.e. each parent and children will now has its own "elements" ?

Comment: 2) Each Form has a to-many relationship to its sub-forms, *and* a to-many relationship to its elements. – 1) Your question is unclear to me.